# Rails session Couldn't find User with username = signout; Why is User Controller looking for that?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, session, activerecord, controller

I'm working through the Michael Hartl Tutorial and am having trouble getting sign-outs to work.

Instead of ID'ing by email, I'm working by username.

Signing up and singing in both work fine, but my sign out causes an error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in UsersController#show

Couldn't find User with username = signout

app/controllers/users_controller.rb:9:in `show'
```

Why is it looking in the users_controller, in the show method?  Why is it calling that?  It should be calling sessions controller's delete method, right?

The offending line 9 is:

```
  8  def show
  9     @user = User.find_by_username!(params[:username])
  10 end
```

I don't understand where the parameters are getting passed in (where and to what) that cause it to think "signout" == the username, rather than finding by username and routing to `session#destroy`.  How can I diagnose this?  What can I type in the Rails console to find out what is currently contained in params?

**Update:**

I thought the solution below worked when I tried it immediately, but the problem had just changed from one error message to another. I have moved the routes around as suggested and am still getting

`Request Parameters: {"username"=>"signout"}` just this time it's located in my

```
`Users#show model: users/show.html.erb where line #1 raised: 

undefined method username' for nil:NilClass 

Extracted source (around line #1): 

1: <\h2><%= @user.username %><\/h2> 
2: 
3: <!-- 
4:`
```

And here are the contents of my routes.rb file:

```
   match 'signup', to: 'users#new'
   match 'signin', to: 'sessions#new'
   match 'signout', to: 'sessions#destroy', via: 'delete'

   resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]

   match "/:username"  => "users#show", via: "get"
   resources :users
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing you have a route which looks like this:

```
get "/users/signout" => "sessions#destroy"
```

Before this, you probably have a line that looks like this:

```
get "/users/:username" => "users#show"
```

The problem is that routing to `/users/signout` will match `/users/:username`, and send your request to the `show` action of the `UsersController`, setting `params[:username]` to `"signout"`. You are then calling `User.find_by_username!("signout")`

You need to put your `/users/signout` route *above* your `/users/:username` line so that it is matched before the `/users/:username` route. Remember that Rails stops trying to find a matching route at the *first* one which can match a request URI. Your more generic wild-card routes must appear *after* more specific routes that have the potential to overlap.

---

#### RE: Your update

Your `signout` route requires an HTTP DELETE request, which rails simulates via a POST request with a `_method=delete` parameter.

In order to match this route, you need to use a form or a `button_to` to issue a DELETE request:

```
button_to "Signout", signout_path, :method => :delete
```

Destroying sessions is (in my opinion) a special case where you should accept *any* type of HTTP request. Users should be able to type `/logout` or `/signout` into their address bar and destroy their session via a GET request. I strongly suggest your remove the `via: :delete` and use the following:

```
match 'signout' => 'sessions#destroy'
```

Conversely, you're being too lenient with your `signup` and `signin` routes, which should use GET and POST requests specifically, and route to `new` and `create` actions rather than to the same action.

```
get 'signup' => 'users#new'
post 'signin' => 'sessions#create'
```

---

> What can I type in the Rails console to find out what is currently contained in params?

Nothing. You cannot inspect the `params` hash via the Rails console, because there is no request. You can inspect in your log files by adding `logger.info(params.inspect)`, or in the browser by raising it as an error message: `raise params.inspect`.

Comment: You are still routing to the wrong action. Without seeing your routes, it's impossible to help you. Please don't post them as a comment. Make a new question, or edit them into your existing question.

Comment: Thanks @meagar, I deleted the comment and updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

I also ran into this issue and the fix mentioned by meagar didn't resolve it for me. My issue actually stemmed from JavaScript and the `DELETE` method used in the link. Apparently browsers don't actually support the `DELETE` request without the help of JavaScript.

To reproduce simply turn off JavaScript and try and use a link which makes use of this request and you'll notice it uses a `GET` request instead of the specified `DELETE`. Ultimately I needed to include application.js which requires `rails.js` (or `jquery-ujs` in my case) to resolve this.